# How to authenticate request header, JWT token

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt

I have angular 7 fronted project and asp.net core web API.

After I create JWT web token from web API, I return to fronted and it will save in local storage.
After I want to send request to web API I will put JWT web token to request header part.

That will work fine. So I want to authenticate request using JWT payload data. My JWT payload data have logging user name, user role some of information.

I want to check it's valid token when get product details by http get request. Can you help me for authenticate in asp.net core web api.

asp.net core web api, Angular 7 cli

### Startup.cs - WEB API

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
 {
  options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
  {
  ValidateIssuer = true,
  ValidateAudience = true,
  ValidateLifetime = true,
  ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
  ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
  ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
  IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
 };
});

services.AddMvc();
```

### Build Web token - WEB API

```
private string BuildToken(MYWebApi.Models.CustomerModel user)
{
  var claims = new[] {
  new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId,user.CusId.ToString()),
  new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub,user.CusName),
  new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email,user.CusEmail),
  new Claim("role","user"),
};

 var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
 var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

 var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
  _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
 claims,
 expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
 signingCredentials: creds);

 return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

### Put token to header part - FRONT END

```
 @Injectable( )
    export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{

      constructor(private injector:Injector) { }

      intercept(req, next){
        let serverService = this.injector.get(ServerService)
        let tokenizedReq = req.clone({
            setHeaders:{
              Autherization:`Bearer ${serverService.getToken()}`
            }
         })
        return next.handle(tokenizedReq)
      }
    }
```

### Controller - WEB API

```
[Route("GetProduct")]
        [HttpGet]
        public List<ProductModel> GetProduct(int productId)
        {
            var repo = new MEData.Repository.ProductRepo();

            var productData = repo.GetProduct(productId);

            return productData;
        }
```

Comment: You seem to have it set up, all you need is the Authorize attribute on either your controller or your action method as far as I can see

Comment: I tried it. but then it show all request as 401(unauthorized) request.

Comment: ideally thats the behavior you want, to secure your api. But if you have only certain actions you need to authorize then only mark those actions with the Authorize attribute

Comment: what logs do you have?

Comment: i did not get your idea friend. what do you mean 'logs'?

Comment: Try using Fiddler or browser's develop tools trace the error which returned from api , and tell us what is the error message .

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have `app.UseAuthentication();` code added before `app.UseMvc();` in Configure method of Startup class

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

And then also add `[Authorize]`attribute at action or controller level based on your requirements

Comment: Then the only reason can be that jwt token is not valid. Have you tried decoding the token using https://jwt.io/?

Comment: Does web api work return data without applying authorization?

Comment: For testing try setting `ValidateIssuer = false,  ValidateAudience = false,` in Startup.cs

Comment: same result friend.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following options below, in addition to `app.UseAuthentication()` call:

**1.** Apply the `[Authorize]` attribute with the `AuthenticationSchemes`

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("GetProduct")]
[HttpGet]
public List<ProductModel> GetProduct(int productId)
{
   //...
}
```

In addition, try adding the following line in `ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddAuthorization();
```

**2.** Try using the `services.AddAuthorization` with policies, and selected scheme

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Jwt", policy =>
    {
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
});
```

Then use the policy using `[Authorize]` attribute

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Jwt")]
[Route("GetProduct")]
[HttpGet]
public List<ProductModel> GetProduct(int productId)
{
   //...
}
```

In general, I think `services.AddAuthorization` line is required. See which of the options works for you.